# .Net CollectionView Access between Multiple Views MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a CollectionView tied to a a ContentView. I have the associated ObservableCollection defined inside of the ContentView Code. I would like to access, update, insert items into the ObservableCollection from another Content View. It would be helpful to see some good examples of how this is done.

I've tried the following:

**1.** I originally tried placing the ObservableCollection inside a ViewModel and setting the variable to static. I can then obtain it from elsewhere and make changes. I read somewhere that this is bad practice. Note: I had to set all my code in here to static to make it all work together.

**OfflineAreasViewModel.cs:**

```
public static ObservableCollection<OfflineAreaModel> OfflineAreas;

public static OfflineAreaModel FindModel(string name)
{
  return OfflineAreas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) as OfflineAreaModel;         
}
```

**OfflineAreasContentView.xaml (bound to OfflineAreasViewModel.cs):**

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="offAreasLstView"
                    ItemsSource="{x:Static viewmodels:OfflineAreasViewModel.OfflineAreas}"
                    HeightRequest="300"     
                    SelectionMode="Single">
```

**Other Content View (to obtain and work with (insert, delete, update) models from the ObservableCollection (this one is bound to code behind):**

```
var model = OfflineAreasViewModel.FindModel(_selMdlName);
```

**2.** I have the ObservableCollection directly inside the ContentView (bindings within the ContentView Code behind). However, in order to access it from other Views, I had to setup a Main Model with a static ObservableCollection that is a COPY of the ObservableCollection inside the ContentView. I could never figure out how to point my ContentView CollectionView to the main Model ObservableCollection.

**OfflineAreasContentView.xaml:**

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="offAreasLstView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding OfflineAreas}"
                    HeightRequest="300"     
                    SelectionMode="Single">
```

**OfflineAreasContentView.xaml.cs:**

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Binded to the ObservableCollection CollectionView 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<OfflineAreaModel> OfflineAreas
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<OfflineAreaModel>)GetValue(OfflineAreasProp);
        set
        {
            SetValue(OfflineAreasProp, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(OfflineAreas));
        }
    }
//later in code
MainModel.OfflineAreas = OfflineAreas;
```

**MainModel.cs:**

```
internal static ObservableCollection<OfflineAreaModel> OfflineAreas { get; set; } = null;

internal static OfflineAreaModel FindOfflineAreaModel(string name)
{
    if (OfflineAreas != null)
       return OfflineAreas.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name) as OfflineAreaModel;
    return null;
}
```

Similar to my first code, I have another control where I execute FindOfflineAreaModel to modify the models tied to the ObservableCollection.

Thoughts or examples of best ways to solve this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-8.0

Comment: I would recommend reading about the [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm), then move the shared collection into a service that can be injected into each ViewModel via [constructor injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/dependency-injection). An alternative would be to use a messenger, like Jason proposed with the link he provided.

Comment: Do you mean ContentViews or ContentPages? That's a big difference. Are you using Shell?

Comment: I'm using ContentView's (not duplicated though). I'm using Shell too (setup standard .NET Maui app in Visual Studio, .NET7). I would love to see an example of "I would recommend reading about the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern, then move the shared collection into a service that can be injected into each ViewModel via constructor injection". I've not been able to get this to work with ContentViews.  I've just started looking at Messenger too, but the examples I've seen are between pages (not ContentViews).

Comment: That's why I asked. ContentViews typically don't have their own ViewModels but rather bind to the ViewModel of their parent Page. Please update your code to reflect the setup you have and clarify this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to say first that everything you do is technically correct.

Having no business logic in the ContentView is the right design choice, and having a separate ViewModel for business logic is an acceptable one.

About your "Messenger" concerns; it does not matter what it is:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<SomeMessageModel>(this, async(message, value)..
```

The message model is the data you want to pass. The `message.Value` is the way you access it in the method.

When you want to send message:

```
 WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SomeMessageModel());
```

(It is really that simple, just needs CommunityToolkit.MVVM)

About your "constructor injection", you may use something like:

```
public class AreaRepository : IAreaRepository
{
     //Implement GetAreaCollection method from the interface
}
```

Injected as singleton, in MauiProgram.cs.

Both suggestions you got will work, but now hear me out.

Let's take something for example, as simple as a Button.

We do not have ButtonViewModel. We do not have ButtonClickedMessage. (Well we sort of have, but not in this context). We do not have ButtonHandlingService.

We have exposed bindable command, that we use directly in our main ViewModel, using binding.

So, if you want to reuse interface, one way is to create a ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyControlTemplate">
    <Grid BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
        ...
        <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        ...
```

To be able to use `MyCommand`, we add it to the ContentView as a bindable property:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MyCommandProperty = 
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyView));
```

And of course we add the property itself:

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
    get => (ICommand)GetValue(MyCommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value);
}
```

And you can use it with something like:

```
<controls:MyView  ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MyControlTemplate}"
                  MyCommand="{Binding ViewModelCommand}"
```

The ControlTemplate is reusable XAML interface.

The View is reusable mechanical only code and bindable properties.

The ViewModel holds the business  logic, but it is not ViewModel of the ContentView, but bound to the Page itself.

And then on top of this design you can do the injecting and messaging. (And you should).

Comment: I got the WeakReferenceMessenger totally working now. I've setup several Messages being passed between my two Content Views.  I make a request to OfflineAreasContentView to get an OfflineAreaModel.  I also send requests to update, insert, and delete models.  Its working great between 2 Content Views.  I can provide code if anyone is interested. Let me know?  H.A.H:  I'll have to 'chew on' the ControlTemplate idea some more.  As for now, I'm able to get the code working with the WeakReferenceMessenger stuff.  Thank you everyone.